# Git (Bitbucket) + ECR - how to keep the same repository:tag for two environments

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ecr

I'm new to GIT, and I'm using bitbucket as my git repository. The following is the content of my bitbucket-pipeline.yml file.

```
image: python:3.7.4-alpine3.10

pipelines:
  tags:
    *:
      - step:
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - pip
          script:
            - pip3 install awscli
            - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ECR_AK} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ECR_SK}
            - eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 | sed 's;https://;;g')
            - docker build -f Dockerfile -t ${PROD_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jimmy-repo:${BITBUCKET_TAG} . 
            - docker push ${PROD_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jimmy-repo:${BITBUCKET_TAG}
            - docker push ${PROD_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jimmy-repo:latest
  branches:
    'test-*':
      - step:
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - pip
          script:
            - pip3 install awscli
            - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ECR_AK} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ECR_SK}
            - eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 | sed 's;https://;;g')
            - docker build -f Dockerfile -t ${TEST_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jimmy-repo:${BITBUCKET_BRANCH} . 
            - docker push ${TEST_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jimmy-repo:${BITBUCKET_BRANCH}
            - docker push ${TEST_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jimmy-repo:latest
```

I can trigger this pipeline to build image, and upload it to Amazon ECR via branch or tag. However, I have two environments in different account, one for testing and one for production. I want both environments to use the same repository name and tag (e.g. jimmy-repo:1.0, jimmy-repo:2.0, jimmy-test:2.1). In the pipeline for tags, I can obtain the tag using the ${BITBUCKET_TAGS} variable, but it seems that I cannot do the same for branches. My branch name is like test-jimmy instead of a version number.

I hope the two environment using the same repository_name:tag_name via the pipeline. I was wondering if there is a way to achieve my requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to trigger the deploy to an environment with a `branches` pipeline but somehow reference a git tag? What tag if the pipeline was triggered by an arbitrary commit pushed to a branch?